# Get all apps running time on android

Tags: java, android

Hiii, 
I am working on an app in which i have to get the `running time` of all the apps that are installed on the device.
So, is it possible to know how long somebody else's app is running for on the phone? Ex: How long is the gmail app running on the phone?

Is there any `API` for this or we have to develop are own logic to make it work???

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901690/get-start-time-of-process

Comment: But, how can i find other application's time that from boot-time, how much time that app runs???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of each service's start time by using ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.activeSince, described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.html#activeSince). Here's a snippet that retrieves the times for all service processes.

```
 ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

 long currentMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();        
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

 for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo info : services) {
     cal.setTimeInMillis(currentMillis-info.activeSince);

     Log.i(TAG, String.format("Process %s with component %s has been running since %s (%d milliseconds)",
             info.process, info.service.getClassName(), cal.getTime().toString(), info.activeSince));
 }
```

Comment: scottt, can you tell me that what type of time this code is returning me? because i am not getting that how it is telling us the running time of apps.

Comment: The Log statement is logging the start time and how any milliseconds the background service processes have been running. You'll want to use the same method calls that the Log statement is using to do something with the data.