# Android. getting application's running time

Tags: android, performance

Can i get application's running time. I read [Get all apps running time on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903604/get-all-apps-running-time-on-android) , but it about service info. My goal is a service that  find out if the application is running more than hour.
What classes and functions can help me?

I need to know time of all application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're talking about your own app, measuring time from itself, you could set starting and ending points within onCreate/onDestroy and onResume/onPause. Those methods will use System.currentTimeMillis().

If your app is being measured, you could also use static flag, like:

```
public static boolean running = false;
```

Set it to true onCreate(), and back to false onDestroy().

Comment: @MrKosherno: Well, in that case, I'm thinking this may be a task for shell, as I see no API for this. So I'd maybe try to get start time of a process using:
"ls -lt /proc/" + your_process_id